# Need help on implementing a simple Bid Tracker in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

For a college assignment I have to implement an interface for a Bid Tracker. Some simple functions for the bid tracker are:

- Record a user's bid on an item
- Get all the bids for an item
- Get all the items on which a user has bid

This should not have a GUI or DB persistence.

I have created a class and interface as below and my solution is based on two hashtables holding the data. My question is,is there a better design than using two hash tables? Also is this design ok?

BidTrackerImpl

```
 public class BidTrackerImpl implements BidTracker {

ItemDAO itemDAO = new ItemDAOImpl();


public void addBid(Bid bid, int itemId) throws ... {
    Item item = itemDAO.getItemById(itemId);
    item.addBid(bid);
}

public List<Bid> getAllBids(int itemId) {
    ...
}


public Set<Item> getAllItems(int userId) {
...
}
```

The DAO uses two hash tables to store the data so I can access by either key (I use locks to ensure thread safety in the DAO methods).

```
public class ItemDAOImpl implements ItemDAO {

Hashtable<Integer, Item> itemsByItemId = new Hashtable<>();
Hashtable<Integer, Set<Item>> itemsByUserId = new Hashtable<>();
...

@Override
public Item getItemById(int itemId) {

...
```

Comment: Honestly, I think the design is fine. I had to re-read everything to understand how the HashTables were being used, but once I got it, it seems to make sense at first (and second) glance. The main thing with using the HashTable is that it does not allow null keys (which is good), and it is synchronized, which is good if your application is multi-threaded (which, given your last sentence, it sounds like it is). You mentioned thread-safe locks, which is perfectly fine technically, however they may not be necessary ultimately, depending on which HashTable method you're calling.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I used the locks in a couple of places, one was to keep the two hash tables in sync when adding an item.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, fair enough. You might also consider posting your code (probably the complete code) over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you're still concerned. You might get a better answer over there.